# Construct a object list from multiple instances of a terraform module

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to figure out how to turn multiple module instances into a map of objects. I have a map of "Customer". I then want the public IP of each of the created customers to build a list of firewall rules. The Customer module has many outputs including "name" and "public_ip_address" The AzureSQLFirewall module expects a map of objects each attributes "name" and "ipAddress".

Main Module:

```
module "Customer"{
    for_each              = var.customers
    source                = "./customer"
    customerName          = "${each.value["name"]}"     
}

module "AzureSQLFirewall" {
    source                  = "./azureSQLFirewall"
    azureSQLServerID        = module.BaseInfrastructure.sql_server_id
    azureSQLAllowedIPs      = { for v in module.Customer: 
                                {
                                name = v.name,
                                ipAddress = v.public_ip
                                }
                              }
}
```

AzureSQLFirewall.tf:

```
terraform {
    required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_firewall_rule" "azureSQLFirewall" {
    for_each = var.azureSQLAllowedIPs
    name             = each.value.name
    server_id        = var.azureSQLServerID
    start_ip_address = each.value.ipAddress
    end_ip_address   = each.value.ipAddress
}

variable "azureSQLServerID"{
    type = string
}

variable "azureSQLAllowedIPs" {
    type = map(object({
        name = string
        ipAddress = string
    }))
}
```

EDIT: Turns out, I was quite close:

```
azureSQLAllowedIPs      = { for k,v in module.Customer: k => {
                            name = v.customerName,
                            ipAddress = v.public_ip}
                          }
```

Comment: I do not believe `for_each` meta-argument values can depend upon exported resource attributes.

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Any errors?